# Gym, meditation and studying

Tags: training, gym, health, eating-habits

I am doing sports and going to gym for several years now. I am student and month ago I started meditating. I would like to know how would you organize, in what order would you:

- Go to training
- Meditate
- Study
- Eat

I am kinda lost and just I want to mention that I am always doing all of those things in afternoon if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for an order for these things?

I just stopped being a student but I would be inclined to do

1. Train
2. Eat
3. Meditate
4. Study

You should eat soon after training to make sure you actually get the benefits of your workout. Then meditating to get yourself into the mindset to study makes sense.

Comment: Tnx, I am grateful that you wrote order and explained it